# Finding columns that do not match existing primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to add a Foreign Key to a table, but database, Sql Server 2005, does not like it.

It says that columns do not match an existing primary key or unique constraint.

How can I find the columns in question so I can delete/change them and add the foreign key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do a left join to the parent table on the key in question, then examine the values in the child table where the value in the left-joined parent table are null.

For example, if this was your schema...

```
table1:
    myKey int primary key,
    ...other columns...

table2:
    otherKey int primary key,
    myKeyFromTable1 int
    ...other columns...
```

You'd do this:

```
select distinct
    t2.myKeyFromTable1

from table2 t2

left join table1 t1 on t1.myKey = t2.myKeyFromTable1

where t1.myKey is null
```

That would give you the distinct values in `table2` that wouldn't have a corresponding parent in `table1`.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT 
   ForeignKey 
FROM 
   FK_TABLE f 
LEFT JOIN 
   PK_TABLE p ON f.ForeignKey = p.PrimaryKey 
WHERE 
   p.PrimaryKey = NULL
```

That should do it.

ForeignKey = the column you want to make into a foreign key
PK_TABLE = the table you want the foreign key to reference
PrimaryKey = the column ForeignKey will be a foreign key to.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
  FROM FK_Table
 WHERE ForeignKey NOT IN (SELECT PrimaryKey FROM PK_Table);
```

This works as written for single-column keys.  It can also work for multi-column keys if your DBMS allows the notation:

```
SELECT *
  FROM FK_Table
 WHERE (FK_Col1, FK_Col2) NOT IN (SELECT PK_Col1, PK_Col2 FROM PK_Table);
```

Not every DBMS supports this, though.  This formulation with NOT EXISTS should work most places:

```
SELECT *
  FROM FK_Table
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM PK_Table
                     WHERE FK_Col1 = PK_Col1 AND FK_Col2 = PK_Col2
                  );
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have TableA with a column X, and TableB with column Y. And you want to make Y a foreign key, such that all values of TableB.Y are values in TableA.X, correct?

To do so, TableA.X needs to have either a primary key or a unique constraint on it. It sounds like that is not the case. Make TableA.X unique first, then define your FK from TableB.Y referencing TableA.X

Comment: I think that the statement creating the FK is passing the 'is there a PK or unique constraint on the PK table' test.  The problem is that part way through verifying that every row in the FK table matches some value in the PK table is finding that there are values in the FK columns that do not match any row in the PK table - so the key cannot be created.